# Find "mystring" in files and return only certain portion of matching lines

Tags: windows, command-line, search, find, findstr

I have below command to list out every file in current directory and it's sub-directories containing "mystring" along with the line where search string match is found.

```
@echo off
setlocal
findstr /s mystring *.txt >> searchResult.list
endlocal
exit
```

But the tricky part is I don't want the filename and path to be printed in the result. Also I don't want the whole matching line either, the whole matching line is like below:

```
Somestring::mystring('the_str_i_need', the(string i don't need));
```

And I only need `the_str_i_need` part of the line to be printed in "searchresult.list" file.

How can I achieve these things with `findstr` or any other alternative command ?

Comment: If you use a construct like foreach (`for /R` ?) and then use `findstr` on the specific %%var, you can suppress the filename. returning a substring can get "hairy." see, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769435/batch-script-substring-from-string. Of course, you can process the result file using something like notepad++ which is open source and handles regular expressions in find/replace.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a small test file containing the string you are looking for and a seperate line in the question showing the **exact** output you would like when "mystring" is found.

Comment: it's not possible with findstr. It's much easier to do that with powershell https://stackoverflow.com/q/40780784/995714